# Nuclear binding and internal energy

Tags: nuclear-physics, mass-energy, fusion, binding-energy, tight-binding

A section of some article:

> When you cool a body at rest its internal energy decreases. Since energy is related to mass, here $E=m_0c^2$, where $m_0$ is the rest mass, the rest mass of the body decreases. Similarly, when a reaction occurs in which the products of the reaction are in a less energetic state than the reactants, the kinetic energy of the products is increased over that of the reactants. By a less energetic state I mean the electrons (chemical reaction) or nucleons (nuclear reaction) are more tightly bound so the atoms or nuclei of the products have less internal energy than the internal energy of the reactants, and this decrease in internal energy is a decrease in rest mass.

Here, why does being tightly bound decreases the internal energy of the nucleons and in turn decreases the rest mass of the nucleons and this "decreased" converts to energy during fusion?

Comment: You should post a reference to the article you quote from.

Comment: [Energy is stored in the interaction fields](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/290893/44126).

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/515288/2451