# Why is internal energy of nucleons ∝ to binding energy?

Tags: energy, mass, mass-energy, fusion, binding-energy

In fusion , as two light nuclei fuse , the relative binding energy experienced by each nucleon is increased and hence the internal energy of the nucleons is decreased which by E=mc² causes a decrease in the rest mass of the nucleon. Thus the total mass is decreased in the fused nucleus which converts to energy due to the conservation of mass. Here why does internal energy decrease with increase in the binding energy?

Kindly correct the theory if wrong :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Nuclear binding and internal energy](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/686170/)

Comment: On Physics SE you should not repost a question closed (even if reworded).  You can make edits *to the original* which clarify why it's not a duplicate and that would be automatically added to the reopen queue so people can vote to reopen it.

Comment: Maybe the answers here will help https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/515288/